# Finding Week-on-Week, Month-on-Month and Year-on-Year returns

Tags: dataframe

I have a price series in a dataframe, with a datetime index. Just appending the top 5 rows of the price series, but I basically have data all the way from 2020-04-01.

| Date | CTH3 Comdty |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-28 | 78.95 |
| 2022-11-25 | 80.18 |
| 2022-11-23 | 82.90 |
| 2022-11-22 | 82.42 |
| 2022-11-21 | 79.78 |

So for example, the weekly return for 2002-11-28 should be based on the price from 5 business days ago, i.e. 2022-11-21, and so (78.95 - 79.78)/79.78 = -1.04%

I would like to calculate week-on-week (WoW) return, month-on-month (MoM) return, year-on-year (YoY) return for each day. For MoM and YoY, it should be based on the price from exactly 1 month or 1 year ago respectively, but if that day is not a business day and there is no price, then to take the price from day before and so on. For this I know I can use .ffill or .bfill in some way.

My current thinking is to use .loc and use a for loop to input the 1 week ago, 1 month ago, and 1 year ago prices as 3 different columns and then proceed to do the % calculation. But this seems a tad bit tedious. How would I go about doing this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.iloc`, you can also try `.iat`.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html